# Strange Typescript error with union types

Tags: typescript

I have an `Optional` type:

```
export type Optional<T> =
  | {
  hasValue: false;
}
  | {
  hasValue: true;
  value: T;
};
```

and a contrived generic type `Value`:

```
type Value<PAYLOAD> = {
  value: PAYLOAD;
};
```

This function, as expected, is error-free:

```
function workingAsExpected1(msg: Optional<string>) {
  const v: Value<Optional<string>> = {
    value: msg,
  }
}
```

Now, I define a `SpecialValue` generic type which is essentially equivalent to the `Value` type, but is necessary to cause the issues that I'm having:

```
type SpecialValue<PAYLOAD> = PAYLOAD extends undefined
  ? never
  : Value<PAYLOAD>;
```

Now, when `msg` is defined in the scope of a function, everything works as expected:

```
function workingAsExpected2() {
  const msg: Optional<string> = {
    hasValue: true,
    value: '',
  };
  const v: SpecialValue<Optional<string>> = {
    value: msg,
  };
}
```

But when I define `msg` as a parameter to the function -- with the exact same type -- I get an error under `v`:

```
function notWorking(msg: Optional<string>) {
  const v: SpecialValue<Optional<string>> = {
    value: msg,
  };
};
```

"Property 'value' is missing in type '{ hasValue: false; }' but required in type '{ hasValue: true; value: string; }'"

What am I missing here? Why does `SpecialValue` cause an error where `Value` doesn't, when they evaluate to the exact same type? Why does it work when I define the variable in scope, but not when I define it as a parameter, even though they're the exact same type?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyYYEsIDsCGANgDwAqAfHALwCwAUHHAD5wDe9jAFvgM4BqRAK7AAXHABmRHsADc9AL4dmbJd35DRCKMLkM4ANw1jSu%20bvpIUcAYWHEACgEEAmgBk0jgCKUqKvYdtNJzcPT1NzOnFBXABjbDw4AHdoAGssXABzRx4AUXBgOOAAEwBGAAoAWx4MsQx4ghIeGCh0jPIASj9GGLwmuHw4nFwxGzs6oaJiJpbM8h8uxgMjOCqMgBolRToti2RUAGUUGKwiUeAHF3cveeCrzzhQGGBcIp44aKLgcXTipQB%20OC4YD6YBQJQjDQXELXCJRWL1JKpVrZPJHJ5FABMZU67D0PVwfVWtUwE0azVa81xizgajOYmawg2ekYAWEYgA5OymYwzEp8X0BvUxIcCidCGdiOM8JNphTKUoWctVty4LztvR6HDBglcBAYAB1JGZSrVYn1GXk2Y4vm9eCCobCo5iiVShpTS1teXMpaBMTKzbhIA)

Comment: Inside `workingAsExpected` the compiler uses [control flow analysis on assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to narow the type of `msg` to `const msg: { hasValue: true; value: string;}`, but inside the body of `notWorking()` there is no such assignment so it has to treat `msg` as the full union type.  You can call `notWorking(msg)` with any `Optional<string>` you want, even ones where `hasValue` is `false`.

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer, but maybe you can first [edit] your question to reduce the code to a [mre] like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG6eXm)?  It seems that `SpecialValue<T>` and `Value<T>` are not really directly relevant.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz But then why does `workingAsExpected1` work? The only difference between this and `notWorking` is `Value` vs `SpecialValue`.

Comment: `SpecialValue<T>` and `Value<T>` are different types; the former [distributes over unions in `T`](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) while the latter doesn't.  `{value: {hasValue: false} | {hasValue: true, value: string}}` and `{value: {hasValue: false}} | {value: {hasValue: true, value: string}}` are not considered to be the same type. If you're asking about *that* difference, then the control flow analysis happening in `workingAsExpected2` is probably not relevant and you should reduce to something like [this](//tsplay.dev/wg69BW)

Comment: There are a few times when you say that several types are "the same" and "equivalent" when they're not.  In order to keep the question to a reasonable scope, maybe you can limit yourself to asking about just one of these seemingly-equivalent types... whichever one you are primarily concerned with.  You can always open more than one question.  Otherwise the answer will be composed of multiple sub-answers which are not related to each other.

Comment: Ok, so forget `workingAsExpected2` then. I just cannot understand what the difference is between `workingAsExpected1` and `notWorking`. Does `SpecialValue<Optional<string>>` not directly evaluate to `Value<Optional<String>>`? If not, why not? I don't understand how distributive conditional types play into this, as the conditional type seems very straightforward -- `Optional<string>` does not extend `undefined`, and therefore `SpecialValue<Optional<string>>` is equal to `Value<Optional<string>>`.

Comment: So do you want an answer to this question explaining that `SpecialValue<T>` and `Value<T>` are not the same even when `T` does not extend `undefined`, and how to address it?  Or do you want to abandon this question in favor of the one you just opened?  Or do you want both answered?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your program makes a semantic distinction between `null` and `undefined` for some reason, you don't need the ceremony of wrapping your value in an object and using an extra property to discriminate whether a potential value exists.

Instead, you can use the built-in type utility [`NonNullable<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to narrow a value, and use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to make it easier to make the discrimination in your code. Consider this example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3MKlOIBMIAzAS2IjoG4AoLgel6gBNAPakoAYzjEowABasA1lGGMZ8gM4zw0MACd2zScGhxNcKI1rjgzYcThVGw3QFtlqgESzTANQekIDy5LYmtbaQgAD2Z1YE10DAAKADd-CAAuPABKTNTyAKgYqAA5O2KKcjhEclRMKABvLigofih9YFJdaTyCgEJsXFoGFjY6KAAycage6H7cMkpuZtaAYSkoZCh1WWdjUZlhdKa2iA6u6bSofpIK7gBfHhCwuyg6YQBlYRdT+WIAcwA6sw5H58tAUmlMvAkKhYrpWH8MFkGsdmKpElEYnEIWCssjGs1mjMWgI4Qjjg9mhByOpoATCcTWgsqEQhkxWOwKVwHnwBGgNFAHOphFBvJo5CY6KliMA4H9oCoNhAEYLqtBgCLSLS1NAPMyYrIPBY4C5mOQQO5ee5lJBdHANbpNKwoCBRLoJMIGAdXjFxPDTfZjIKoGBhHsbA4LmCjq0ALSi4DAMDqdL8BjJanCW0AOhcwgAXmbKtnnH9eBBiLGAKrvXhvcTqXgAiCIXgAKTgqXefuYYGAvAASkwIPpQhBeAB5W325yNgAywj+hgcAH19dsV6Z1Mw-sRvjKrfHZInk6m6xAM+QsyPcwWi3AS7oyxXq7X643m62O12e33B8PR3EccpxHGdHV4cpKANFdxGEBwIHUcQERXa87QdQ8EyTFM0wvTMczzQtKAfUty0rGs62EBsmxbdtOzgbt4T-IdGBHCsgMnacHUbKcbDsVdxG8VhyWCKxeOkP59FOKBEnsb4AH4oQQZAUDJf4kRRZpZOgOS5NwAByAFnHIOg9KWEgTQgDgSS2YB4X+Y5YOIYUamzK8-kSAADAAJakrygAASeotLuDysnuHgJIgU5EjC6yPB8ygRUM3RjKCSLorZEZ2Fi1p4t8pKjLoNLJOAGSKhygQ8sSqBktSrh0tKvS9IqqAqr84qosagAhItmqs3KEr8nrKA8IA)

```ts
type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined;

// You can think of this type predicate as a functional form of "hasValue"
function exists <T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  // return value !== undefined && value !== null;
  // Can be shortened to:
  return value != null;
}

function doSomethingWithValue (value: Maybe<string>) {
  if (exists(value)) {
    value // string
  }
  else {
    value // null | undefined
  }
}

// This also has the advantage of being able to use the "nullish" family of
// of operators in your code to discriminate a potential value:
// - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment
// - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator
// - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

function greet (name?: Maybe<string>) {
  name ??= 'World';
  name; // string
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}

greet(); // "Hello World"
greet(undefined); // "Hello World"
greet(null); // "Hello World"
greet(''); // "Hello "
greet('Bill'); // "Hello Bill"
```

Comment: I should've made this clearer in my question, but the `Optional` type is a contrived type that is analogous to a more meaningful type in my app. It needs to be a union type of objects. I realize after my discussion with jcalz that what I'm really looking for is how to define `SpecialValue` so that it maps directly to `Value` if its generic type parameter isn't undefined. I suppose I'll make another more direct question for this.